# Сумма последовательности 1+2^2+3^3+…+N^N

Tags: c++

> Дано натуральное число `N`. Вычислить
>
> ```
> S = 1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + … + N^N
> ```
>
> Формулу возведения в степень не использовать. Язык C++.

Comment: @Devil7, какие у вас есть мысли по решению задачи? Там, кстати, не степень случайно?

S = 1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + … + N^N

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(void){
  int S=1,N;
  cin>>N;
  for(int i=2;i<N+1;i++)
    S=S+(11*i);
  cout<<S<<endl;
  system("pause");
}
```

### решение для степени:

```
void main(void){ 
int S=0,N,F; 
cin>>N; 
for(int i=1;i<N+1;i++)
{
  F = 1;
  for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    F *=i;
  S = S + F; 
} 
cout<<S<<endl; 
system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: а что, если NN, при N=11 дожно  быть равным 1111, а не 121?

Answer (score 0):

Задача вполне корректна. Степень использовать нельзя, зато логарифм не запрещено

```
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int n = 13;
int s = 0, i, m = 10, p = 0;

for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )  {
    if ( p < (int) log10((double) i) ) {
        p ++;
        m *= 10;
    }
    s += i*m+i;
}
printf("%d ", s);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Вы можете пояснить что означает NN в случае, если N>10? Мне кажется, что это совершенно неочевидно.

Comment: N=10 NN=1010
N=100 NN=1001000
по-моему очевидно, поскольку никаких ограничений N не указано

Comment: S = 1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + … + N^N

Comment: ОК. Вообще нифига не было видно =)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку n^n растёт очень быстро, используем библиотеку gmp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int main (void) {
    int n;
    mpz_class s = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
        mpz_class w = i;
        for(int j=1; j < i; j++) w *= i;
        s += w;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Компиляция `g++ -o example example.c++ -l gmpxx -l gmp`

Answer (score 0):

```
long long answer(size_t N)
{
    std::valarray<long long> v(N);
    std::iota(&v[0], &v[N], 1);
    long long res = v.apply([](long long k){
        size_t n = k;
        for (long long i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            k *= n;
        return  k; }).sum();
    return  (res < 0) ? 0 : res;
}
```